# Unable to read cookie value on client side that was set in GWT RPC

Tags: gwt, cookies, gwt-rpc

I had a GWT servelt on whose doGet method, I created a cookie as shown below:

```
Cookie nameCookie = new Cookie("name","adam");
response.addCookie(nameCookie);
```

I tried to read this on the client side as

```
String name = Cookies.getCookie("name");
```

But the output of string variable name was coming out as *undefined*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by finding out that while creating a cookie, you also have to set the path for it.
So in the server side,

```
Cookie nameCookie = new Cookie("name","adam");
nameCookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(nameCookie);
```

Now the following client side code returns the proper value as *adam*

```
String name = Cookies.getCookie("name");
```